# Android: Listview Scrollbar

Tags: android, android-listview

[image]Can I customize List View scrollbar???????

a)The thumb should be clickable and dragable.

b)Should contain buttons on each side, which slide the list view up and down accordingly.

c)The scrollbar track should be wider.

Thank you.

Comment: yes you can. there are attributes for that. scrollbarTrack* and scrollbarThumb*

Comment: I used:
android:scrollbarThumbVertical
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" 

But these are not working.
I also followed the link: http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/
but all in vein.

Comment: search " custom Listview in android" :)

Comment: Please see the updated question.. This is what i want to achieve as a listview scroller.
I searched for everything i could have, but not getting any appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

To customize scroll bar, you can use below style.Apply this style to your scrollbar.

```
<style name="your_style_name">  
<item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
<item name="android:scrollbarStyle">outsideOverlay</item>
<item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
<item name="android:fadeScrollbars">false</item>
<item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scroller_image</item>
```

Where scroller_image is your image for scroller thumb.If you want to add buttons for up and down, you can place two buttons above and below of Scrollview.And programatically scroll the scroll bar on button click.
For that purpose, you can use following code,

```
scrollview.scrollTo(5, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, use OnScrollListener on ListView and OnTouchListener on VerticalSeekbar, like below:

```
mListView.setOnScrollListener(this);
mScrollbar.setOnTouchListener(this);


@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mCurrentPosition = firstVisibleItem;
    if (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount > 0) {
        int progress = mScrollbar.getMax() * firstVisibleItem
                    / (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount);
        mScrollbar.setProgress(progress);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Adapter adapter = mListView.getAdapter();
    if (adapter == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (adapter instanceof HeaderViewListAdapter) {
            adapter = ((HeaderViewListAdapter) adapter).getWrappedAdapter();
        }

        int itemCount = adapter.getCount();
        if (itemCount == 0)
            return false;
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            scroll(event.getY());
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            scroll(event.getY());
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            scroll(event.getY());
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
   }
}

private void scroll(float height) {
        mItemCount = mListView.getAdapter().getCount();
        int scrollHeight = mScrollbar.getHeight();
        Log.e(TAG, "Scrollbar height: " + scrollHeight);
        int position = (int) ((height / mScrollbar.getHeight()) * mItemCount);
        Log.e(TAG, "Position scroll: " + position);
        if (position < 0)
            position = 0;
        else if (position >= mItemCount)
            position = mItemCount - 1;
        mListView.setSelection(position);
    }
```